# VBA Excel - Filter multiple fields

Tags: vba, excel, autofilter

I'm trying to filter three column. Please see the following code:

```
.Range("$A:$S").AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:=Array("Ongoing", "Completed"), Operator:=xlFilterValues

.Range("$A:$S").AutoFilter field:=4, Criteria1:=Array("AQs", "Prop", "RF", "RP", "SQs"), Operator:=xlFilterValues

.Range("$A$1:$S$" & ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count).AutoFilter field:=10, Criteria1:=">" & _
  Format(Date - 7, "mm/dd/yyyy"), Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="=Not Known", Operator:=xlOr
```

Basically, i'm filtering field 1 based on 'ongoing' and 'complete'; field 4 on 'aqs', 'prop', 'rf', 'rp', etc. Finally i want to filter all of that for dates within a week of now AND the value 'Not known'.

It filters through the first two fields fine... but the last filter line doesnt work correctly. I get the 'Not Known' values and i get everything that is within a week of today BUT i dont get anything which is in advance of today... this is a problem.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Define your range as well as your worksheet in a [With ... End With statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wc500chb.aspx) then use the range definition to set all three filters.

```
Dim lr As Long, dat As Range, vDATEs As Variant
ReDim vDATEs(1 To 1)
vDATEs(1) = "Unknown"
With Sheets("Sheet3")
    If .AutoFilterMode Then .AutoFilterMode = False
    lr = .Cells(Rows.Count, 10).End(xlUp).Row
    With .Range("$A:$S").Resize(lr, 19)
        .AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:=Array("Ongoing", "Completed"), Operator:=xlFilterValues
        .AutoFilter field:=4, Criteria1:=Array("AQs", "Prop", "RF", "RP", "SQs"), Operator:=xlFilterValues
        With .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, .Columns.Count).Offset(1, 0)
            If CBool(Application.Subtotal(103, .Columns(10))) Then
                For Each dat In Intersect(.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible), .Columns(10))
                    If IsDate(dat) Then
                        If dat.Value < (Date - 7) Or dat.Value > Date Then
                            ReDim Preserve vDATEs(LBound(vDATEs) To UBound(vDATEs) + 1)
                            vDATEs(UBound(vDATEs)) = Format(dat.Value, "mm/dd/yyyy")
                        End If
                    End If
                Next dat
            End If
        End With
        .AutoFilter field:=10, Criteria1:=(vDATEs), Operator:=xlFilterValues
    End With
    'If .AutoFilterMode Then .AutoFilterMode = False
End With
```

You cannot have three criteria on an Autofilter field without resorting to an array. Build the array from the values showing and then use that array to filter your final field.

Comment: Thanks for this -- it still doesnt provide the result i need. to be clear, field 10 needs to filter for dates more than 7 days old. Therefore, anything older than seven days will be shown. However, i also need dates in advance of today/now... this isnt happening.

Comment: You would need to cycle through the dates and build an array of all dates excluding the 7 day period but including Unknown then filter on the array.

Comment: Awesome -- thanks. I've been playing aroud with the spreadsheet in the interim... i rekeyed some of the offending dates... and guess what... autofilter is working correctly. !? I cant figure out what has happened... other than someone might have changed the date format (although it looks the same as it ever did). Is this an issue with Excel???